# How to force dovecot startup errors to appear in mail.err?

Tags: dovecot

Dovecot won't start on my Ubuntu 18.04 server:

```
 dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-04-27 09:59:23 UTC; 9h ago
     Docs: man:dovecot(1)
           http://wiki2.dovecot.org/
  Process: 6563 ExecStop=/usr/bin/doveadm stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10127 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dovecot -F (code=exited, status=89)
 Main PID: 10127 (code=exited, status=89)
```

`/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` contains the following:

```
auth_verbose = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = no
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
mail_debug = yes
verbose_ssl = yes
```

Trying to restart dovecot produces no error, yet it doesn't start.

`/var/log/mail.err` and `/var/log/mail.log` contains no reference to dovecot. There is no `/var/log/dovecot` file or folder.

What do I need to do to force dovecot to log? It's impossible to troubleshoot if it doesn't log anything.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a bug in dovecot.

The most recent update now shows the error message. It was an error in one of the config files.